# How to conditionally run JavaScipt based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a responsive JS element that looks like an accordion on mobile view, like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp and looks like tabs on desktop view, like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp. I am running into trouble as the functions to do this interfere with each other after one has been fired because of the JS editing the classList. My HTML and JS are below. I thought about resetting the className back to normal when the screen resizes? I am not sure how to go about doing that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 726px)' href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 725px)' href="desktop.css">

<div class="container">
<!-- accordion markup -->
   <button class="accordion active" id="btn1">tab 1</button>
   <div class="accordion-content show" id="content1">
     <p>Integer vel arcu ac dolor tincidunt dapibus.</p>
   </div>
   <button class="accordion" id="btn2">tab 2</button>
   <div class="accordion-content" id="content2">
     <p>Integer vel arcu ac dolor tincidunt dapibus.</p>
   </div>
   <button class="accordion" id="btn3">tab 3</button>
   <div class="accordion-content" id="content3">
     <p>Integer vel arcu ac dolor tincidunt dapibus.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 725px)").matches) {
  for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
    accordions[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle('is-open');
  
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        // accordion is currently open, so close it
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        // accordion is currently closed, so open it
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
} else  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 726px)").matches){
  const toggleActive = (buttonId) => {
    const buttonClicked = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    const currentActiveBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
  
    currentActiveBtn.classList.remove("active");
    buttonClicked.classList.add("active")
  
  }
  
  const toggleShow = (contentId) => {
    const contentToShow = document.getElementById(contentId);
      const currentShownContent = document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0];
    
    currentShownContent.classList.remove("show");
    contentToShow.classList.add("show")
  }

  const buttons = [...document.getElementsByClassName("accordion")];
  
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      toggleActive(button.id)
      
      const contentId = "accordion-content" + button.id.charAt(button.id.length - 1);
      
      toggleShow(contentId);
    });
  
  })
}
```

Comment: Your JS contains `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 725px)"` and your HTML `media='screen and (max-width: 726px)'` so there's a pixel difference. Same for the other media query definition

Answer (score 0):

The way i've done this in the past is to listen for a window resize event, then depending on the size, swap out the relevant classes from the dom elements. here's a code example using jQuery.

```js
/* Initialize the timer variable */
let timer;

/* Listen for window resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
  /* Clear the timer */
  clearTimeout(timer);
  /* Set a timeout so the function is not firing a million times, then run the callback */
  timer = setTimeout(swap_classes, 500);
});

function swap_classes() {
  /* Clear the timer again just in case */
  clearTimeout(timer);
  /* Check the window size */
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    /* Set all your classes for tabs */
    console.log("Tabs");
  } else {
    /* Set classes for accordion */
    console.log("Accordion");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```